# The following expression has a mistake if( x = 0 ). Please provide the corrected version

Tags: c++

I am attempting a quiz question of C++ programming "if statements"
but the quiz says that there is an mistake with:

```
if(x=0)
```

I dont uderstand what it was asking.

I think it should be:

```
if(x=0){}.
```

Comment: `if(x=0)` should be `if(x==0)`.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(x == 0)
```

`=` is a assignment

`==` is a boolean conditional check.

Answer (score 2):

Your if-statement condition should be:

```
if (x == 0)
```

Rather than:

```
if (x = 0)
```

The reason for this is that (=) represents the assignment operator. If we take the following statement:

```
int num = 5;
```

Then, by using the assignment operator here, we set the variable on the left the value on the right; here, we set `num` to 5. The assignment operator only does this unless it is overloaded (research "overload operators in c++"). This operator cannot be used to make comparisons.

To make a comparison between 2 values/variables, we use the comparison operator, which is 2 equal signs together (==). This operator checks whether the value or variable on the left side of it equals the value or variable on the right side of it. If they are equal, then it returns true, else it returns false. You want this operator in your if-statement.

Comment: Can the downvoter of this question please explain where I went wrong?